# Second order polynomials and linear prediction in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of five variables (1 independent and 4 dependent). I want to estimate a linear model with second order polynomials and all cross terms then compute the R squared and calculate the MSE on the test sample.

getting the fit is easy

```
fit2 <- lm(num_carriers~.^2, data = trainSlim)
```

Is there something similar to .^2 that I can use for the predict function. Maybe something like

```
pred2 <- predict(fit2, testSlim.^2
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use `poly`. Here is what it is designed for:

> Returns or evaluates orthogonal polynomials of degree 1 to degree over
>   the specified set of points x: these are all orthogonal to the
>   constant polynomial of degree 0. Alternatively, evaluate raw
>   polynomials.

```
qf <- lm(mpg ~ poly(hp,2, raw=TRUE), data = mtcars)
qf
predict(qf, newdata = mtcars)
```

You can check that this gives the same output as specifying polynomials by hand:

```
qf2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + I(hp^2), data = mtcars)
qf2
```

It is important to specify `raw=TRUE` to disable the use of orthogonal polynomials (i.e, simply use `x` and `x^2`)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My problem isn't the "fit" part of the question. My problem is that I can't use my fit to predict anything because my data (testslim) doesn't contain the necessary variables